# Buttons in table appear to wrap_content when they should match_patent

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have two layouts for the same activity. This one is for landscape and should have two rows of buttons, each with two buttons (2X2 grid), and a banner ad at the bottom. Everything is positioned correctly, but the buttons still appear to be set to wrap_content for layout_width. I want them to be all the same size, regardless of the text.

I added a border to the table to I can see that it is match_parent, but the width of the buttons are all with of the widest button in each column. I want them to all fill the cell of the table and the table should fill the parent window.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/table_options"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/table_border">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="1dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="1dip"
        android:onClick="onHuntClick"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_hunt"
        style="@style/button_style"
        android:text="@string/main_activity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/other_lists"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="1dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="1dip"
        android:onClick="onListsClick"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_listit"
        style="@style/button_style"
        android:text="@string/other_lists" />
</TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/table_border">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/web_site"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="1dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="1dip"
        android:onClick="onWebClick"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email_color"
        style="@style/button_style"
        android:text="@string/email_vendor" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/invite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="1dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="1dip"
        android:onClick="onInviteClick"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_invite"
        style="@style/button_style"
        android:text="@string/invite" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/main_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/main_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_options"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_activity"
                style="@style/button_style"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_hunt"
                android:onClick="onHuntClick"
                android:paddingBottom="1dip"
                android:paddingLeft="6dip"
                android:paddingRight="6dip"
                android:paddingTop="1dip"
                android:text="@string/main_activity"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/other_lists"
                style="@style/button_style"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_listit"
                android:onClick="onListsClick"
                android:paddingBottom="1dip"
                android:paddingLeft="6dip"
                android:paddingRight="6dip"
                android:paddingTop="1dip"
                android:text="@string/other_lists"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/web_site"
                style="@style/button_style"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email_color"
                android:onClick="onWebClick"
                android:paddingBottom="1dip"
                android:paddingLeft="6dip"
                android:paddingRight="6dip"
                android:paddingTop="1dip"
                android:text="@string/email_vendor"/>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/invite"
                style="@style/button_style"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_invite"
                android:onClick="onInviteClick"
                android:paddingBottom="1dip"
                android:paddingLeft="6dip"
                android:paddingRight="6dip"
                android:paddingTop="1dip"
                android:text="@string/invite"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically what I did was place the two buttons inside a LinerLayout with horizontal orientation whose width is equal to parent and gave each the parameter of weight="1". That means that they will have the same width (50% of parent). If you wanted one to be twice as wide as the other you would use weight="2" on one, the other one would get weight="1"

Comment: Why would this work? A little explanation would be great, instead of just the code.

Comment: I added some explanation at the bottom

Comment: Beautiful! That got it and I learned something along the way. Thanks.